# SwiftUI: pushViewController:animated: called on ... while an existing transition or presentation is occurring

Tags: swift, swiftui, alert, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to navigate to a detail view from within an alert.

Here a minimal reproducible code sample for the error:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let items = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    RowView(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RowView: View {

    let item: String

    @State private var isShowingNext = false
    @State private var isShowingAlert = false

    var body: some View {

        let itemNumber = Int(item)!
        let isEven = itemNumber % 2 == 0

        ZStack {
            if isEven {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Hello"),
                    isActive: $isShowingNext,
                    label: {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                ).hidden()
                Button(
                    action: {
                        isShowingAlert.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("\(item) (with alert)")
                    }
                )
                .alert(isPresented: $isShowingAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Alert")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                            .font(.title),
                        message: Text("Hello"),
                        primaryButton: .destructive(
                            Text("Navigate"),
                            action: {
                                isShowingNext = true
                            }
                        ),
                        secondaryButton: .cancel()
                    )
                }
            } else {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Hello"),
                    isActive: $isShowingNext,
                    label: {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you click on e.g. the item `2 (with alert)` the alert shows up but the error also appears in the console. Then when you click on `Navigate` inside the alert it doesn't navigate.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Alert` and `NavigationLink` present another view. And you cannot present a view when the other view is already presented on current view.

You have to wait until the `Alert` is hidden, and then you can present the `NavigationLink`.

The easiest way to do this is to pass `Binding` to `NavigationLink`, which will make sure that the `Alert` is not displayed:

```
struct RowView: View {

    let item: String

    @State private var isShowingNext = false
    @State private var isShowingAlert = false

    private var isShowingNextBinding: Binding<Bool> {
        Binding(
            get: {
                !isShowingAlert && isShowingNext
            }, set: {
                isShowingNext = $0
            }
        )
    }

    var body: some View {

        let itemNumber = Int(item)!
        let isEven = itemNumber % 2 == 0

        ZStack {
            if isEven {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Hello"),
                    isActive: isShowingNextBinding,
                    label: {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                ).hidden()
                Button(
                    action: {
                        isShowingAlert.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                    Text("\(item) (with alert)")
                }
                )
                    .alert(isPresented: $isShowingAlert) {
                        Alert(
                            title: Text("Alert")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                                .font(.title),
                            message: Text("Hello"),
                            primaryButton: .destructive(
                                Text("Navigate"),
                                action: {
                                    isShowingNext = true
                                }
                            ),
                            secondaryButton: .cancel()
                        )
                    }
            } else {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Hello"),
                    isActive: $isShowingNext,
                    label: {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you.